# Получить тело запроса Spring

Tags: java, spring, post, request

Добрейшего денёчка!

Я хочу из формы отправить на определённый экшн какие-то данные. Как мне получить параметры запроса?

**Форма**

```
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" method="post" >
                  <tr style="font-size: 14px">
                    <td>Начало временного промежутка</td>
                    <td><input id="datepicker-1" type="text" th:name="*{starting_date}" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="font-size: 14px">
                    <td>Конец временного промежутка</td>
                    <td><input id="datepicker-2" type="text" th:name="*{ending_date}" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr style="font-size: 14px">
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Найти"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                  </tr>
                </form>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Метод**, получающий запрос. Мне нужно получить от пользователя параметры (что бы обрабатывать их).

```
    @PostMapping
    String search(Model model) {
        

        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: Почему вопрос про тело запроса?

Comment: @RomanC Здравствуйте. Потому что я хочу в форме отправить значение инпутов и получить их по именам в методе обрабатывающем этот запрос. Что бы это выглядело как-то так: RequestBody.getParameter("starting_date");

Comment: Это что новый способ получения параметров? Или в Request body у вас есть такой метод? Приведите пример кода, где вы пытаетесь заделать так как вы хотите, и укажите что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через @RequestBody  получаете объект с параметрами.
Как то так:

```
    @Controller
    public class Controller {
     @PostMapping("/request_address")
      String search (@RequestBody RequestObject requestObject){
       // RequestObject-объект с параметрами, который приходит в запросе
       //       .....
       return "index";
       }
     }
```

Comment: Так мне нужно создавать объект под каждую форму на сайте?

Comment: Class, не объект. Да, что бы не усложнять задачу с разбором приходящих данных с веба, надо создать необходимые классы. А объекты, то есть экземпляры класса, уже Спринг сделает.